# Como alterar TextView de uma View em outra View?

Tags: java, android

Estou enfrentando o problema, abaixo:

Tenho 2 layout xml: list_single.xml e tela_autorização.xml
Tenho 1 classe: Autorização.class

Na classe Autorização tenho:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.tela_autorizacao);
```

Mas quero alterar a cor do campo KEY_IAESTORNO, só que este campo está no list_single.xml, tentei fazer isto:

```
  teste = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.KEY_IAESTORNO);

  teste.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Claro que não funcionou, está nulo, justamente porque ele está lendo o layout-> tela_autorização.xml e o campo está em list_single.xml

Estou usando um adapter na list:

...{

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        NodeList nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PAI);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e2 = (Element) nl2.item(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_IAAUTNUM,
                    "Nº Autorização: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAAUTNUM));
            map.put(KEY_IAESTORNO, sit + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAESTORNO));
            map.put(KEY_IAENTNOME,
                    "Entidade: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAENTNOME));
            map.put(KEY_IAASSNOME,
                    "Associado: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAASSNOME));
            map.put(KEY_IAASSPORT,
                    "Portador: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAASSPORT));
            map.put(KEY_IACARTFMT,
                    "Cartão: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IACARTFMT));
            map.put(KEY_IAPARPRIM,
                    "Prim.Parc.: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAPARPRIM));
            map.put(KEY_IAPARCOUT,
                    "Demais: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAPARCOUT));
            map.put(KEY_IAQTDPAR,
                    "Nº Parc.: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAQTDPAR));
            map.put(KEY_IAVALOPE,
                    "Valor Total: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAVALOPE));
            map.put(KEY_IANOMMES,
                    "Mês Venc.: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IANOMMES));
            map.put(KEY_IAESTNOME,
                    redetxt + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAESTNOME));
            map.put(KEY_IAESTCNPJ,
                    cnpjtxt + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAESTCNPJ));
            map.put(KEY_IADATA, "Data: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IADATA));
            map.put(KEY_IAHORA, "Hora: " + parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAHORA));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            NUMAUT2 = parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAAUTNUM);
            SITU = parser.getValue(e2, KEY_IAESTORNO);
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        if (SITU.equals("ESTORNADA")) {

            btnEstornar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        } else {

            btnEstornar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_single_xml, new String[] { KEY_IAAUTNUM,
                        KEY_IAESTORNO, KEY_IAENTNOME, KEY_IAASSNOME,
                        KEY_IAASSPORT, KEY_IACARTFMT, KEY_IAPARPRIM,
                        KEY_IAPARCOUT, KEY_IAQTDPAR, KEY_IAVALOPE,
                        KEY_IANOMMES, KEY_IAESTNOME, KEY_IAESTCNPJ,
                        KEY_IADATA, KEY_IAHORA }, new int[] {
                        R.id.KEY_IAAUTNUM, R.id.KEY_IAASSNOME,
                        R.id.KEY_IAENTNOME, R.id.KEY_IAASSNOME,
                        R.id.KEY_IAASSPORT, R.id.KEY_IACARTFMT,
                        R.id.KEY_IAPARPRIM, R.id.KEY_IAPARCOUT,
                        R.id.KEY_IAQTDPAR, R.id.KEY_IAVALOPE,
                        R.id.KEY_IANOMMES, R.id.KEY_IAESTNOME,
                        R.id.KEY_IAESTCNPJ, R.id.KEY_IADATA,
                        R.id.KEY_IAHORA

                });

        TextView estorno =(TextView) adapter.getItem(2);
        estorno.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Rogers, sua pergunta esta um pouco confusa, pelo que entendi você quer recuperar a `View` principal da sua `Activity` certo (Se não for, tente esclarecer um pouco melhor)? Se você fizer: `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` dentro de sua `Activity` ou `getView` em seu `Fragment`, ele retorna a raiz da sua `View`. A partir dessa `View` você pode buscar os demais elementos. Se a TextView esta dentro de um `ListView` você precisa: Ou acessar os dados que alimentam o item da lista (pelo `Adapter`) ou buscar algum filho, usando o `ViewGroup.childAt`.

Comment: @Wakim editei, v~e se consegue entender?

Comment: Acho que entendi, você quer alterar apenas um, dada uma posição, ou quer alterar todos (uma `View` que esta dentro do layout dos itens do `ListView` que tem id `KEY_IAESTORNO`)?

Comment: apenas a cor de um @Wakin,

Comment: Apenas a cor do KEY_IAESTORNO entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, estou montando uma resposta com alguns detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se precisa customizar a `View` de um item do `ListView` crie um subclasse de `SimpleAdapter` e inclua a lógica de customização nele. Por exemplo:

```
public class MeuSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sua logica de customizacao, recuperando outras Views dentro do item.
        // Alem disso, de uma olhada no padrao View Holder,
        // ajuda a dar fluidez na sua lista.

        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.KEY_IAESTORNO);

        int atributoDoModelo = (...);

        // Buscar no modelo a informacao sobre a cor desse item
        text.setTextColor(atributoDoModelo);
        // ou
        text.setBackgroundColor(atributoDoModelo);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Com esse conceito é possível fazer muito mais coisa: modificar visibilidade, adicionar `EventListeners`, popular `Views` mais complexas.

Agora, se a lista já foi construída e **algum evento ocorreu e precisa alterar a cor do item de forma pontual**.

Podem ocorrer dois casos:

1. O item não está visível, logo nesse caso não há o que fazer. Apenas alterar algum  atributo do seu modelo que o `Adapter` use para dar cor ao elemento.
2. O elemento está visível, nesse caso há duas soluções:

   1. Alterar seu modelo e usar o `notifyDataSetChanged`, isso irá forçar a atualização dos itens que estão visíveis na tela.
   2. Marcar as `Views` que compõem o layout do item do `ListView` com a sua posição e iterar sobre os filhos do `ListView` buscando essa tag. Ao recuperar o filho alvo, alterar o seu layout. O código ficaria assim.

      **Alterando o `Adapter` para marcar a `View` com sua posição:**

      ```
      // Crio uma subclasse anônima do SimpleAdapter,
      // pode ser em um arquivo separado se achar melhor.
      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...) {

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

              // "Tageio" a View que representa o item com a posição dela no `Adapter`.
              view.setTag(R.layout.list_single_xml, position);

              return view;
          }
      };
      ```

      **Código para modificar a cor do `TextView`:**

      ```
      public void alterarCorDoItem(int position, int cor) {
          ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list);
          int size = list.getChildCount();
          boolean achei = false;

          // Itero sobre os filhos que estão visíveis
          for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
              View child = list.childAt(i);
              Integer adapterPosition = (Integer) child.getTag(R.layout.list_single_xml);

              // Achei a view alvo
              if(adapterPosition != null && adapterPosition.intValue() == position) {

                  TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.KEY_IAESTORNO);

                  textView.setTextColor(cor);
                  // ou
                  textView.setBackgroundColor(cor);

                  achei = true;
                  break;
              }
          }

          if(! achei) {
              // Posicao nao esta visivel, alterar modelo para quando
              // ficar visivel, ficar com a cor correta
          }
      }
      ```

Comment: Wakim não consegui fazer, tenho criar uma classe para fazer isto?

Comment: Usando a classe anonima ele não coloca a tag? Qual parte não funcionou?